# Using llvm::Linker to programatically find unresolved externals

Tags: c++, c, linker, llvm, clang

I'm using clang/llvm to programmatically compile and link bits of C source.  I'm finding that the llvm Linker doesn't seem to report the fact that unresolved externals exist in a module as an error.

I've the following code (forgive the length, but this really is the minimum required):

```
int CompileAndLink()
{
    llvm::InitializeNativeTarget();

    std::string code = "int UnresolvedFunction();\n"
                       "int main() { return UnresolvedFunction(); }";

    clang::DiagnosticOptions diagnosticOptions;
    clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter tdp( llvm::outs(), diagnosticOptions );    
    llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticIDs> diagIDs( new clang::DiagnosticIDs );
    clang::Diagnostic diag( diagIDs, &tdp, false );

    clang::FileSystemOptions    fsOptions;
    clang::FileManager fm( fsOptions ); 

    clang::SourceManager sm( diag, fm );
    clang::HeaderSearch hs( fm );   

    clang::TargetOptions targetOptions;
    targetOptions.Triple = llvm::sys::getHostTriple();
    clang::TargetInfo* ti = clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo( diag, targetOptions );         

    clang::HeaderSearchOptions  headerSearchOptions;        
    clang::LangOptions langOptions;
    clang::ApplyHeaderSearchOptions( hs, headerSearchOptions, langOptions, ti->getTriple() );

    clang::PreprocessorOptions ppo;
    clang::Preprocessor pp( diag, langOptions, *ti, sm, hs );

    clang::FrontendOptions frontendOptions;
    clang::InitializePreprocessor( pp, ppo, headerSearchOptions, frontendOptions );

    pp.getBuiltinInfo().InitializeBuiltins( pp.getIdentifierTable(), langOptions );

    llvm::MemoryBuffer* sourceBuffer = llvm::MemoryBuffer::getMemBufferCopy( code );
    sm.createMainFileIDForMemBuffer( sourceBuffer );

    clang::Builtin::Context bic( *ti );
    clang::ASTContext astc( langOptions, sm, *ti, 
                           pp.getIdentifierTable(), 
                           pp.getSelectorTable(), 
                           bic, 
                           0 );

    llvm::LLVMContext   lc;
    clang::CodeGenOptions codeGenOptions;
    llvm::OwningPtr<clang::CodeGenerator> cg;
    cg.reset( clang::CreateLLVMCodeGen( diag, "clang_test", codeGenOptions, lc ) );
    if( cg == NULL ) {
        printf( "could not create CodeGenerator\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    clang::ParseAST( pp, cg.get(), astc );
    if( tdp.getNumErrors() ) {
        printf( "error parsing AST\n" );
        return -2;
    }

    llvm::Module* new_module = cg->ReleaseModule();
    if( !new_module ) {
        printf( "error generating code\n" );
        return -2;
    }

    llvm::Linker    linker( "clang_test", "clang_test", lc, llvm::Linker::Verbose   );

    std::string error;
    if( linker.LinkInModule( new_module, &error ) || !error.empty() ) {
        printf( "link error\n" );
        return -3;
    }

    llvm::Module* composite_module = linker.getModule();
    if( composite_module == NULL ) {
        printf( "link error\n" );
        return -3;
    }

    llvm::ExecutionEngine *pEngine = llvm::ExecutionEngine::create( composite_module, 
                                                                   false,
                                                                   &error );
    if( !error.empty() || pEngine == NULL ) {
        printf( "error creating ExecutionEngine\n" );
        return -4;
    }

    llvm::Function* f = composite_module->getFunction( "main" );
    if( f == NULL ) {
        printf( "couldn't find main function\n" );
        return -5;
    }

    // This will abort with the message:
    // LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'UnresolvedFunction' which could not be resolved!
    std::vector<llvm::GenericValue> params;
    llvm::GenericValue result = pEngine->runFunction( f, params );  

    printf( "function main returned %llu\n", result.IntVal.getZExtValue() );

    return 0;
}
```

No errors happen anywhere until we call runFunction near the end, which gives the error "LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'UnresolvedFunction' which could not be resolved!" before aborting.

I kinda expected LinkInModule or getModule to fail with some error, but this isn't the case.    My question is: is there some way to determine that a module has unresolved externals, so as not to crash and burn when trying to execute the code?  I've been spelunking through the llvm source for quite a while, and so far can't find what I'm looking for.

I'm using llvm/clang 2.9 on Mac OS X (x86_64), if that matters.

**Edit**: I've found a private function called `GetAllUndefinedSymbols` in the llvm sources (llvm-2.9/lib/Linker/LinkArchives.cpp), which appears to do what I want.  I guess I was hoping there was an actual API for this, something I missed?

Comment: I ended up doing more-or-less as @servn suggested, which is a variation on the code in GetAllUndefinedSybols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, nobody has ever asked for such an API, so none exists.  I'm not entirely sure what you would do with such an API, anyway... any non-trivial program will reference symbols not defined in any .bc file, like `malloc`.

If you really want to check, something like the following should work:

```
for (Module::iterator I = M->begin(), E = M->end(); I != E; ++I)
  if (I->isDeclaration())
    UndefGlobals.insert(&*I);

for (Module::global_iterator I = M->global_begin(),
                             E = M->global_end();
     I != E; ++I)
  if (I->isDeclaration())
    UndefGlobals.insert(&*I);
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is run some code in the JIT, without having it abort if there are unresolved externals.  Your code does work (though, as @Anton points out, some things are magically resolved by the JIT, leading to false positives).

Answer (score 2):

LLVM linker is used to link the Modules. Given that it's perfectly valid for Module to have the external declarations no errors should be given. So it's up to you to decide whether you need to error in such situation (some externals e.g. to C library functions in some situtation might be automagically resolved by JIT)

So, servn's code is what you have to do here.

Comment: Anton, do you know where/how the JIT looks for its list of automagically resolved dependencies? is there a place i can add a unresolved dependencies that can be look up?

Comment: Just via dlopen'ing the main binary. Look into DynamicLibrary class for more info